# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Problem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
 else:
            find_textarea = (
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div/form/textarea')
            WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(find_textarea)
            )
            comment_box = bot.find_element(*find_textarea)
            WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(find_textarea)
            )
            comment_box.click()
            comment_box.send_keys(comment)

            time.sleep(2)

            find_button = (
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div/form/button')
            WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(find_button)
            )
            button = bot.find_element(*find_button)
            WebDriverWait(bot, 100).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(find_button)
            )
            button.click()

            time.sleep(random.randint(7, 30))
```

Comment: Please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your question.

Comment: Can we have the entire errorStacktrace here ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ahgul\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Instabot\run.py", line 168, in <module>
    main(data)
  File "c:\Users\ahgul\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Instabot\run.py", line 150, in main
    WebDriverWait(bot, 120).until(
  File "C:\Users\ahgul\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Instabot\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: ı was doing automatic insta commenter, its working but after some time crashing